# Slow performance for data transformation for each column value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, loops

```
df_list = []

for i in tqdm(item_list_short):
    
    df = query_result_df[query_result_df['id_item']==i]
    # calculate mean
    mean = np.mean(df['price']) 
    # calculate standard deviation
    sd = np.std(df['price'])
    # create empty list to store outliers
    outliers = []
    
    if sd == 0:
        outliers = 0
    else:
        # detect outlier
        for i in df['price']: 
            z = (i-mean)/sd # calculate z-score
            outliers.append(z) # add to the empty list
    df['z-score'] = outliers
    df_list.append(df)

df_score = pd.concat(df_list)
df_score
```

Right now if the length of `item_list_short` is in few millions then it will take few days to finish. Checked the time using `tqdm` library.

Data `query_result_df`  looks something like this:

```
 id_item        id_seller   price
     11           1          40
     22           2          30
     33           3          10
     33           4           9
     44           5           8
```

and the list `item_list_short` contains list of all unique `id_item`.

Comment: I'm wiling to bet adding sample data would increase your odds of getting an answer here.

Comment: Added data. Thanks :)

Comment: you might want to look up groupby

Comment: what is your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two major factors for slow performance here:

**1) Filtering in the loop instead of grouping**

At the moment your code takes `O(rows * items)`, while a standard `.groupby()` would take `O(rows)`, i.e `items` times faster. Check out some [examples](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html)

In your case that would be:

```
df['z_score'] = df.groupby('id_item')['price'].transform(
    lambda rows: (ps - ps.mean()) / ps.std() if ps.min() < ps.max() else ps * 0.0
)
```

If you need to speedup things to max, spending a bit more code, try this:

```
mean_and_std = df.groupby('id_item')['price'].agg(['mean','std']).reset_index()
df = df.merge(mean_and_std, on='id_item')
df['z_score'] = (df['price'] - df['mean']) / df['std'].apply(lambda s: s or 1.0)
```

Please report what speedup you got with this.

It seems to be the best practice for such calculations so it definitely worth reading all the [article](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html).

**2) Avoiding vectorized operations**

Appending elements one by one is way slower than writing something like

```
z_score = (df['price'] - df['mean']) / df['std']
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your comment. I am bit confused what to remove and what to keep. Is it possible to put the entire replaced code here as well? @andrew

Comment: Yes, the code snippets I wrote substitute the whole code you pasted. Should I elaborate?

Comment: No, thanks it's fine. I got what you did. I am just trying to replace all my code with yours and some of the suggestion as above, I will report the speed. But looks like tqdm is not working as expected. May be it needs to be used in a different way to make tqdm work?

Comment: I don't see a way to use tqdm in this solution. In fact I cannot see any sped-up solution that keeps tqdm.

Comment: Yea looks like it. I have used the `time` library to track the speed but this won't help me to predict how long I have to wait for the giant data to finish processing. Lets hope it computes soon :) Thanks once again for your time.

Comment: Good solution @Andrew! It reduced the time from 172 hours to 64 seconds :D Well done mate.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are trying to compute z-score per group. See the code below that doesn't use any loops and works with groupby in pandas

```
from scipy.stats import zscore
df.groupby(["id_item"]).price.transform(lambda x : zscore(x,ddof=1))

0         NaN
1         NaN
2    0.707107
3   -0.707107
4         NaN
Name: price, dtype: float64
```